# Manipulating file read permissions in Java

Tags: java, filesystems, nio

I'm trying to remove read permission for a file using java

```
File f = new File("Test.txt");
if(!f.exists())
    f.createNewFile();
System.out.println(f.setReadable(false));
```

The code above always return false. I would expected the opposite since the file I try to manipulate is newly created.
I need to do work on both OS windows and linux.

Comment: Which part of the code is returning `false`? You need to check whether `f.createNewFile()` is returning `true` or `false`.

Comment: f.setReadable(false) returns false

Comment: What about the access right on this file for the user running this java program ?  Maybe if the user does not have right to change permission it will not work.

Comment: The question is what did `f.exists()` and `f.createNewFile()` return. You haven't considered the case where the file does exist and you don't have write access to it. In any case I don't see the point of creating an empty file just to test your write access to it. Most calls to `File.createNewFile()` shouldn't be made at all.

Comment: The file i want to create is a new file that doesn't exist on disk and  I want to write something on it. The file shouldn't have read permission.